# MatSort is not working in Mat-Table Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I try to sort data in Angular table using MatSortModule but is not working in Angular 9
I don't get any error but still sorting doesn't work. How can I fix this..?

------ TS -------

````
   this.dataService.GetList().subscribe(resdata => {
      this.tblength = resdata.length;
      this.load = false;
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(resdata);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }) ```

-----HTML-------
````

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="tblength > 0">
       <table id="day" mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
           <!--Sl.No.-->
           <ng-container matColumnDef="slno">
               <th class="mn50 text-center" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Sl.No </th>
               <td class="mn50 text-center" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let i = index;"> {{i+1}} </td>
           </ng-container>
           <!-- Member Name -->
           <ng-container matColumnDef="official_name">
               <th class="" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> Member Name </th>
               <td class="" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><span class="underline" (click)="SelectedData(element);EditDialog(element.baptism_id);">{{element.official_name}}</span></td>
           </ng-container>
           <!-- Baptism Name -->
           <ng-container matColumnDef="baptism_name">
               <th class="" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> Baptism Name </th>
               <td class="" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.baptism_name}} </td>
           </ng-container>
           <!-- Family Name -->
           <ng-container matColumnDef="fam_name">
               <th class="" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> Family Name </th>
               <td class="" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.family_name}} </td>
           </ng-container>
           <!-- Register Ref no -->
           <ng-container matColumnDef="ref_no">
               <th class="mn50" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef  mat-sort-header> Reg. Ref. No. </th>
               <td class="mn50" mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.reg_no}} </td>
           </ng-container>
           <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true;"></tr>
           <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
       </table>
   </div>
   <!-- pagination -->
   <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[50, 10, 100]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
```

Comment: Did you import `MatSortModule` in your module?

Comment: Yes It is imported

Comment: Because you have an *ngIf="tblength > 0", I had this problem before, try to delete the *ngIf and you will notice sorting will work as expected.